# Unable to pass parameters to SSRS report in ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, parameters

Hi I am getting an error in supplying parameters to an SSRS report deployed on server in ASP.NET page.

Please refer to the code below and let me know where is the issue?

```
ReportExecutionService rs = new ReportExecutionService();
        string rptURL = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rptURL"].ToString();
        string rptPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Page1SLScorecardReortForDownload"].ToString();
        //Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[] paramlist = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[3];
        //paramlist[0] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("Week", "2013-05-03");
        //paramlist[1] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("year", "Fiscal Calendar 2013");
        //paramlist[2] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("Month", "Fiscal May, 2013");
        ParameterValue[] paramlist = new ParameterValue[3];
        //Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[] paramlist = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[3];
        paramlist[0] = new ParameterValue();
        paramlist[0].Name = "Week";
        paramlist[0].Value = "2013-05-03";
        paramlist[1] = new ParameterValue();
        paramlist[1].Name = "year";
        paramlist[1].Value = "Fiscal Calendar 2013";
        paramlist[2] = new ParameterValue();
        paramlist[2].Name = "Month";
        paramlist[2].Value = "Fiscal May, 2013";

       //ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(paramlist);

        rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        rs.Url = rptURL;
        byte[] result = null;
        string reportPath = rptPath;
        string format = "EXCEL";
        string historyID = null;
        string devInfo = @"<DeviceInfo><Toolbar>False</Toolbar></DeviceInfo>";

        string encoding;
        string mimeType;
        string extension;
        ReportingWS.Warning[] warnings = null;
        string[] streamIDs = null;
        ReportingWS.ExecutionInfo execInfo = new ReportingWS.ExecutionInfo();

        ReportingWS.ExecutionHeader execHeader = new ReportingWS.ExecutionHeader();
        rs.ExecutionHeaderValue = execHeader;

        execInfo = rs.LoadReport(reportPath, historyID);
        rs.SetExecutionParameters(paramlist, "en-us");
        String SessionId = rs.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID;

        try
        {
            result = rs.Render(format, devInfo, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);
            execInfo = rs.GetExecutionInfo();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //AlnErrorHandler.HandleError(ex);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("FyId", Convert.ToInt16(objSession.FyId).ToString()));
            parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("AccountGroupId", cmbAccountGroup.SelectedValue));
            parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("LedgerId", cmbLedgerId.SelectedValue));              
            rptvwMain.ServerReport.SetParameters(parameters);
```

Pass Parameters like this....

Comment: Not working. It says constructor does not take two values. I want to highlight that i am not trying to pass the parameters to report viewer because I did something like this in anothere report and there parameters were easily passed to the reportviewer. I want to get the result of the report and write to a file here later.